# MSTEST/VSTS Reflection Tool

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

Does anyone know of a tool that will spit out a list of all methods with the [TestMethod] attribute within a solution?

What we're trying to accomplish is a review, with the customer, of our Unit Tests (names, not pass/fail status) against the Requirements.  We are using VSTS 2008 and Scrum for Team Systems, so I wasn't sure if this was something that was built in somewhere, or if it's a tool I just need to toss together for our purposes.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS essentially offers this ability for free by generating the TRX file to summarize the results of a test run. There are a number of different ways to run all tests in a project but pick one and off mstest will go running each method with the [TestMethod] attribute and producing a UnitTestResult in the results file.

What you're asking for is essentially what the Test Results window shows you after a completed Test Run. If you're looking for something external to VS, you could always run a simple XSLT transform against the Test Results (.trx) file giving you a customized summary. Here's a very rough sample which proofs the concept, generating an HTML document containing an unordered list with a list item (test name and result) for each unit test:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:vs="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">

                    body { font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; }

                    .pass { color: green; }
                    .nopass { color: red; }

                    h1 { font-size: 13px; margin: 3px; }

                    ul { margin: 3px 20px 3px 40px; }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <h1>Test Results</h1>
                <ul>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="//vs:Results//vs:UnitTestResult" />

                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="vs:UnitTestResult" >
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@testName" />
            &#160;

            <xsl:variable name="Result">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@outcome='Passed'">pass</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>nopass</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

            <b class="{$Result}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@outcome" />
            </b>
        </li>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```